# Spring Data REST persistance MySQL one-to-many embedded objects update(PUT/PATCH)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have two Classes: Object and ObjectProperty, they are connected as one to many relation. So Object has some HashSet of ObjectParameters.

```
public Set<SOPParameter> parameters = new HashSet<>();
```

It Spring Data REST performs POST perfectly, but in case of PUT for replacement or PATCH for updating object with particular id, parameters do not affected at all.
What is a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you post a bit more of code, like the methods that are performing the PATCH and PUT? And also your repository class.

Comment: No specific methods hadles those requests, it relies on Spring Data Rest.
Repository class also doesnt exsists only interface for mentioned tool:

```public interface ObjectsRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Long> {
 Page<Object> findAll(Pageable pageable);
 Object findOne(Long aLong);
 
}```
sorry for bad code formatting in a comments.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
First, annotation orphanRemoval has to be set to true

`@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "sop", orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<SOPParameter> parameters = new HashSet<>();`

Second, handler for setParameters have to be stated:

`public void setParameters(HashSet<SOPParameter> set) {
        if (set != null) {
            this.parameters.clear();
            this.parameters.addAll(set);
        }
    }`